# Remove spaces from words in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have a df which is like this

```
Product
Prod1
Prod 1
Prod2
Prod 2
Prod 2
Prod 3
Prod3  and so on
```

I basically want to convert all these Prod1 , Prod2 and Prod3 etc to categorical variables. For doing that I need to remove the blank spaces between Prod and the number, for e.g.removing space between Prod and 1 so that Prod1 , Prod 1 etc. become Prod1 so that there are no duplicate entries for same product

Expected output for above table

```
Product
Prod1
Prod1
Prod2
Prod2
Prod2
Prod3
Prod3  and so on
```

All answers of strip and all were mentioned for a sentence only . I want an answer which can be replicable to the entire table and remove empty spaces between all the words in a column

Comment: replace({' ':''},regex=True)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str.split().agg("".join)`

**Ex:**

```
df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.split().agg("".join)
#or
#df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.replace(r"(\s+)", "")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Product
0   Prod1
1   Prod1
2   Prod2
3   Prod2
4   Prod2
5   Prod3
6   Prod3
```

Comment: this doesn't match the desired output? it will give `Prod3andsoon` same as the 2nd answer.

Comment: @Datanovice I believe  “and so on” is for the list of data goes on

Comment: ah i see, nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

Let's try `str.replace` with the following pattern to remove spaces *between* `Prod` and `digits`.

```
df['Product'] = df.Product.str.replace('(Prod)(\s+)(\d)', r'\1\3')
```

Output:

```
            Product
0             Prod1
1             Prod1
2             Prod2
3             Prod2
4             Prod2
5             Prod3
6  Prod3  and so on
```

Comment: quick question, what does the \1\3 mean and or do?

Comment: `\1` refers to first capture group, `Prod` in this case. `\3` refers to the third capture group.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be the simplest way!

```
df['Product'] = df['Product'].str.replace(' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
df["Product"] = [i.replace(" ", "") for i in df.Product]
```